# Cannot Import TensorFlow - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have seen TensorFlow installation issues many times on this site. I have tried most of the fixes that I've come across, but none of them have quite worked.

Technical information:

- Windows 10, 64 bit
- Python version: Python 3.6
- PyCharm
- Current conda virtual environment: tensorflow_env, with interpreter as "Python 3.6 (tensorflow_env) (2) C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\pythonw.exe"

Please let me know if I'm missing any important information, so I can add it.

Description of the issue:
In PyCharm, I have the code "import tensorflow" which results in the error mentioned in the title.
Now, when I start typing "import tens" it auto-completes to "import tensorflow" for me (see the figure below), which makes me think that it sees the module in some way, but it just can't import for some reason.

[image]

Additionally, my project interpreter has tensorflow as a listed package (see the figure below).

[image]

In order to install tensorflow, I have tried a number of methods. Here are some of them.

1. pip install tensorflow (resulted in "successful installation of . . .")
2. pip3 install tensorflow (resulted in "successful installation of . . .")
3. A number of ways of upgrading tensorflow (e.g. pip upgrade), most of which have resulted in success messages.
4. Through the interpreter itself, resulting in the following image (note the "Package 'tensorflow installed correctly" message at the bottom.
   [image]

Now that all being said, I can technically import tensorflow using the command prompt and the following commands.

- conda activate tensorflow_env
- python
- import tensorflow (does not result in error)
- import keras (results in "Using TensorFlow backend.")

However, I would like to use this outside the command prompt.

I've tried a few Youtube tutorials (most notably tech with tim's video on the subject, as well as his troubleshooting video), the instructions on the tensorflow website, removing every version of python from my computer and trying again (twice), and the instructions I've seen on other posts on stackoverflow.

I'm certain I'm just missing something simple and obvious, but I need some help figuring out what that is.

I appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you use `conda list` to get the contents of the environment? Also, have you restarted PyCharm after installing? _pip install tensorflow_ Was all that done inside of the Conda environment?

Comment: @AMC Good questions. I used conda list, and the result is very similar to the 2nd figure in my original question. I have restarted PyCharm just now, and tensorflow still cannot be imported. The cmd is in the virtual environment, but as I was checking the virtual environment of PyCharm, I realized there was a letter missing from the line (somehow). I fixed it, and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: _The cmd is in the virtual environment_ What do you mean? _I realized there was a letter missing from the line_ A missing letter where?

Comment: `Go to Files -> Settings -> Project:projectname -> Project Interpreter`
It's possible, that there is a different interpreter choosen for your project then the one you installed tensorflow in.May be you need to activate the virtual environment before choosing interpreter.